# Can I combine <= and = in a always @ clock block?

Tags: fpga, verilog

I want to implement this approximate(*) absolute difference design in a clock block and I want to calculate it within one single clock cycle:

[image]

(*): Approximate because it's correct at an error of 1 (for instance, |61 - 63| = 1).

I could do:

```
    tmp <= ina - inb;
    out <= tmp[7:0] ^ {8{tmp[8]}};
```

but it would delay the result of one clock cycle. Does it make sense to write the following and mix both = and <= ?

```
module code(clk, ina, inb, out);
    input clk;
    input [7:0] ina;
    input [7:0] inb;
    output [7:0] out;

    reg [8:0] t;
    reg [7:0] tt;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    t = ina - inb;
    tt <= t[7:0] ^ {8{t[8]}};
end

assign out = tt;

endmodule
```

Or is there a proper way to write in a single line but obviously I don't want to "consume" two differences.

Comment: Yea, but it is generally considered as a bad coding guideline, because people tend to mix them within the same always block, and use them without fully understanding its intricacies (like Dave explained).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you write to a variable with a blocking assignment before you read it within the same `always` block, *and* you do not try to read outside that block, it's considered a temporary variable and gets synthesized into combinational logic.

Once you try to read it outside the block, it becomes sequential logic and you run the risk of a simulation race condition if that read is synchronized to the same clock edge.

A better coding style is declaring temporary variables inside the `always` block so it cannot be read (or more difficult to read) outside the block.

```
module code(
    input clk,
    input [7:0] ina,
    input [7:0] inb,
    output reg [7:0] out
);
always @(posedge clk) begin
    reg [8:0] t;
    t = ina - inb;
    out <= t[7:0] ^ {8{t[8]}};
end
endmodule
```

Comment: +1. You may want to recall this old post... ;) https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/question-about-un-named-block

Comment: Is it a bad practice to use continuous assignment outside of the always@ block and change the reg to a wire?

```wire [7:0] t = ina - inb;```
<br/>

(Assume "logic" would do the same as "wire" here too).

Comment: @MartinVana https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451692/is-it-necessary-to-seperate-combinational-logic-from-sequential-logic-while-codi

Answer (score 3):

There are two key rules with assignments in clocked always blocks.

1. Do not mix blocking and non-blocking assignments to the same reg. Doing so is likely to cause a synthesis failure.
2. Do not read the result of a blocking assignment from outside the always block where it was set. Doing so can make the behavior of the code unpredictable, because the order in which different always blocks execute is not defined.

Your code follows both of these rules, so it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is perfectly valid as long as you want both your "t" and "tt" outputs to be synchronous. (Also note that you wrote "d" instead of "t", I assume that's a typo.)